# Error while Provisioning SPDistributedCacheService

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, error

Have run a PowerShell script to provision `SPDistributedCacheService` after running `psconfig`.(As I was Patching CU updates to 2016 SP farm) encountered this error:

```
PS C:\Users\***.admin> $InstanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
PS C:\Users\***.admin> $ServiceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {($PSItem.Service.ToString()) -eq $Ins
tanceName -and ($PSItem.Server.Name) -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME}
PS C:\Users\***.admin> $ServiceInstance.Provision()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ServiceInstance.Provision()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command to get SPDistributedCacheService.

```
$Service = Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -eq "Distributed Cache"}
$Service.provision()
```